# Ruby on Rails trying to update a boolean in a user table while logged in as another entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very novice at Ruby and Ruby on Rails.
I am trying to update a web application that has signed up volunteers that require approval before they can access full website functionality.  I added a boolean field to the volunteers database model called :approved that defaults to **false** when a volunteer signs up, and requires a logged in administrator to update it to **true**.
I created an administrator class in my project that can view a list of pending volunteers from the controller:

```
def view_pending_volunteers
    @navbar = true
    @volunteers = Volunteer.where(approved: false)
end
```

In the administrator view I want to use checkboxes associated with volunteer, which when submitted will allow the administrator to update the :approved field in the volunteer table.

I have several issues that are not clear to accomplish this task:

1. In my administrator model I use has_many :volunteers with a migration that put the volunteer_id as a foreign key in the administrator database table.  Is that sufficient to accomplish the task at hand, or do I need to create a join table for :approved?  I can't have volunteers belong_to :administrators because they would not be able to sign up on their own, they need to be created by administrators.
2. I am not sure exactly how to configure the code for checkbox helpers in my administrator view.  I am using form_with but I am sure my code is not correct.  I would like to pass an array of parameters for each check_box associated with the :approved field for the list of pending volunteers back to the controller.

```
<p><b style="color:blue;font-size:24px;">
<%= form_with(model: @volunteer, local: true) do |f| %>
   <% @volunteers.each do |v| %>
   <li>
     Volunteer: <%= x.first_name%> <%= x.last_name%> &emsp;Age: <%= x.age%> &emsp;Description: <%= x.description%>&emsp;
     <%= f.check_box (@volunteers, v.approved, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")%>
                         
    </li>
    <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
</b></p>
```

3. I am not exactly sure how to handle the array of checkbox values that get returned to the administrator controller in order to update the volunteer database table.  Do I need to create a hash in the view (how to do that?) and then loop through the hash to update_attribute(:approved, true) for each checked volunteer?  I have created an update_pending_volunteers method in the administrator controller for the POST operation, but am unclear on the code that should be there because I am unsure the checkbox approach.

Thanks in advance for your patience with a newbie.  This seems like such a simple thing to do but I am not sure of the proper approach.  I have spent quite a bit of time reviewing APIs and videos and stack overflow articles but cannot seem to piece together information that will give me confidence in a particular approach to do this correctly.  Again it seems like such a simple thing to accomplish but has become a source of frustration.

Comment: If approved is on the volunteers table like you say, then you do not need any of these relationships, just update that value and only let administrators do that.  `volunteer_id` should not be in the administrator table, that is backwards.  If an administrator `has_many` volunteers then volunteers would have an `administrator_id`, which is the id of the administrator they `belong_to` and administrators would not have a `volunteer_id`, since they have many.

Comment: Yes you are correct I have it backwards.  I am trying to link volunteers and administrators via the database model because when they were not linked I was getting 'nil' object errors when trying to access the volunteers database table while logged in as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See the comment from Rockwell Rice. Don't create a relationship of any kind for this functionality.
2. Use the URL feature of form_with, not model. You're not acting on one volunteer, you're acting on many. Create a post route (ie. `approve_volunteers`). In the view you would create the checkboxes like this:

```
<%= form_with(url: approve_volunteers_path, local: true) do |f| %>
   <% @volunteers.each do |v| %>
     <div class="field">
      <label class="checkbox">
        Volunteer: <%= x.first_name%> <%= x.last_name%> &emsp;Age: <%= x.age%> &emsp;Description: <%= x.description%>&emsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="volunteers[]" value="<%= v.id %>"> 
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

That should send params through the form like `{"volunteers" => ["1", "3"]}` and leave the rest empty. You might have to play around with those a little. Check your console for the params.

Then in your controller something like:

```
def approve_volunteers
  volunteer_ids = []
  volunteers = Volunteer.where(approved: false)
  volunteers.each do |v|
    if v.id.in?(params[:volunteers])
      volunteer_ids << v.id
    end
  end
  Volunteer.where('id IN (?)', volunteer_ids).update(approved: true)
end
```

3. See above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response it was very helpful.  As mentioned in an answer to Rockwell, it seemed that I needed some link between administrators and volunteers.  becuase I was getting a 'nil' error when trying to access the volunteers database table while logged in as an administrator.  Your form suggestion works great and it returns "Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "volunteers"=>["3"], "commit"=>"Approve"}"  The controller code needs to be tweaked as I get a null in volunteer_ids :  Volunteer Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "volunteers".* FROM "volunteers" WHERE (id IN (NULL))

Comment: I may need to add that the Volunteer model was created with Devise.  Perhaps there is something in the Devise model that is preventing the admin from updating the field in the Volunteer database table.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox code provided by Sam worked perfectly.  My url for the view is "update_pending_volunteers_path."  I need to improve the formatting a little bit.

The code in the controller that worked to loop through the array of volunteer ids that was passed back into the controller is as below:

```
  def view_pending_volunteers
    @navbar = true
    @volunteers = Volunteer.where(approved: false)
  end

  def update_pending_volunteers
    @navbar = true
    params[:volunteers].each do |value|
      Volunteer.find(Integer(value)).update(approved: true)
    end
    redirect_to (administrator_dashboard_path)
  end
```

The volunteers passed into the view have already been parsed to just those that have not been approved, so the volunteer_ids returned as checked are only from that list.